# Generating a list of values from the application of a sequence of operators

Tags: operators

I have a module 'L' that reads:

```
L[f0_,n_]:=Module[{ft=f0}, a[t]={}; Do[AppendTo[a[t], Inr[f0,ft]]; 
ft=U@ft, {n}]];
```

It takes an input function f0, applies unitary operator U repeatedly n-times, i.e. it is a n-fold composition of U on f0. The resulting function after each single composition step is evaluated with Inr (Inr is the inner product here). Finally, the value is added to a list a[t], and so on.

What I am looking to achieve is instead of applying U n-times, (U[U[U...[f0]..], I want to construct an action of a repeated sequence of different operators A,B. For example, A[A[A[B[B[B[A[A[A[B...[f0]..], that likewise amounts to a total of n-fold composition. The list a[t] then should be constructed via Inr employing ft's obtained from each single application of A or B along the composition sequence.

Could anyone provide suggestions how to implement this with Do command, or in some other way! Building a list of the operator sequences and using NestList does not seem to be permissible due to memory constraints since all intermediate values ft are retained. Only a[t]'s are of interest here.

The functions are defined as:

```
U@ft_:=UV InverseFourier[UK Fourier[ft]];
```

i.e. Going between position/momentum-spaces to evaluate application of a potential energy term UV and momentum UK term, where:

```
UV:=Exp[-I V dt];
UK:=Exp[-I K dt];
```

This is the split-operator method solution of a 't'-dependent 2D Schrodinger eq. on a lattice grid. f0 -initial is any discretized 2D function, say a Gaussian. Difference between U and A and B is due to different 'V' terms of 'UV's. Inr on the spatial grid:

```
Inr[f0_,ft_]:=Dot[Flatten[Conjugate[f0]],Flatten[ft]]dxdy;
```

Comment: How do you want to specify the sequence of operators?

Comment: Look up `Composition`, maybe? Either that, or `ComposeList`.

Comment: Or maybe `G[f0, #] & /@ NestList[H, f0, 4]`?

Comment: Or `G[f0, #] & /@ ComposeList[{A, A, B, A, B, B}, x]`? Which of these is closest to what you want?

Comment: @march your 2nd suggestion is closer to what I am getting at. There needs to be over 1000 operator applications to f0 for the particular purpose at hand. If I'm not mistaken ComposeList will retain all intermediate calculations. My fs are a complex functions on a 1024x1024 grid, so this takes up RAM quickly. Same issue with using NestList.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing your issue. It seems like you *do* want to keep each intermediate calculation, because you're appending it to the list. Can you explain?

Comment: When you apply operator H on some 2D complex f you get another f' function. G is an inner product here, i.e. integral of f' * f0 product over all space. So f' and f0 are mapped to a single scalar value. The actual functions f obtained after some sequence of AABBA.. are only used to obtain those scalar values.

Comment: basically we are interested only in a[x] values, but not what actual f's look like..

Comment: I see what you mean. I believe this is a job for a `Sow`/`Reap` construction, because `AppendTo` is notoriously slow, and using `Sow`/`Reap` allows you to gather desired outputs at any time during a `Do` loop. However, I think it will be hard to determine if it's useful without a minimal example showing the actual format of your functions/matrices/etc. Obviously, don't post a 1024X1024 grid, but perhaps you could give an example grid (4x4?) with example `A` and `B`, and your expression for `G`.

Comment: @march i hope this helps

Comment: I think I understand, but one last clarification: `ft` is the 2D discretized wave function, `V` and `K` are the potential and kinetic energies, which means they are *operators* on `ft`. The idea behind the split-operator method is that you propagate a time-step with `K` in momentum-space, then propagate a time-step with `V` in position-space, which is what allows you to write `Exp[-I V dt]` and multiply `ft` by this *element-wise* instead of something like `MatrixExp[-I V dt]` and doing matrix multiplication. Is that right? Finally, do you want `a[x]` at every step, or just after every `U`?

Comment: @march your code does what it should. How would you extend this now when for example U@ft_:=A@A@B@B@ft so that a[x] is Sown via Do after each A,B,.. step (total n-steps, with the given repeating sequence n=4m ) and not after every four steps given by U?

Comment: I can add that, but then what is `G`? Since you are jumping back and forth between position space and momentum space, and you can't take the inner product of a position-space wave function with a momentum-space wave function unless you transform one or the other, then I'm not sure what you want to do. Nonetheless, I'll post a general construction in my answer that perhaps you can adapt accordingly.

Comment: surely we cannot take Inr with f's in different representations like that, mr march. op[1] = U1[#] &; op[2] = U2[#] &; .. where Ui are the u[ft_]'s with different uv's does the job. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions for the functions are as follows:

```
uv = Exp[-I v dt];
uk = Exp[-I k dt];
u[ft_] := uv InverseFourier[uk Fourier[ft]]
inr[f0_, ft_] := Dot[Flatten[Conjugate[f0]], Flatten[ft]] dx dy;
```

where it is understood that `v`, `k`, and `ft` all have the same dimension.

Then, do

```
L[f0_, n_] := Last@Last@Reap@Module[{ft = f0},
  Do[
   Sow[inr[f0, ft = u[ft]]],
   {n}
  ]
 ]
```

---

If instead we have a sequence of operations, and we want to `Sow` a function of the result at each step, I would define the operators as an indexed set of operators, then define a list that includes the order of operations, and apply it.

As a generic example, let's suppose we have three operators `op[1]`, `op[2]`, and `op[3]`, all defined as functions or pure functions of some sort. Let's suppose we want to apply these operators in order, each twice, and then repeat `n` times. Define

```
order = With[{n = 3}, Join @@ Table[{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {n}]]
(* {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3} *)
```

Then, we have some function `g` that we want to apply to the output of these operations at each step. Then:

```
L[f0_, num_] := Last@Last@Reap@Module[{ft = f0},
  Do[
   Sow[g[f0, ft = op[order[[j]]][ft]]],
   {j, num}
  ]
 ]
```

in which case, for instance,

```
L[f0, 5] // Column
```

[image]

For your problem, I would define

```
op[1] = Fourier;
op[2] = Exp[-I k dt] #&;
op[4] = InverseFourier;
op[3] = Exp[-I v dt] #&;
```

and (if this makes sense, which I don't really think it does because you will be taking inner products of wave functions that are expanded in different bases, namely position and momentum bases, but you can work that out four yourself)

```
g[f0_, ft_] := Dot[Flatten[Conjugate[f0]], Flatten[ft]] dx dy
```

Then, everything should work out.